# Function with for loop and logical operators

Tags: dataframe, function, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I want to create a function in python that normalizes the values of several variables with specific condition:

As an example the following df, mine have 24 in total (23 int and 1 obj)

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | A |
| 3 | 3 | B |
| 0 | 0.4 | A |
| 5 | 7 | B |
| 3 | 2 | A |
| 6 | 0 | B |

Lets say that I want to create a new df with the values of Col A and Col B after dividing by factor X or Y depending of whether col C is A or B. ie if col C is A the factor is X and if col C is B the factor is Y

I have create different version of a function:

`def normalized_new (columns):`
`for col in df.columns:`
`if df.loc[df['Column C'] =='A']:`
`col=df[col]/X`
`elif df.loc[df['Column C'] =='B']:`
`col=df[col]/Y`
`else: pass`
`return columns`

`normalized_new (df)`

and the other I tried:

`def new_norm (prog):`
`if df.loc[(df['Column C']=='A')]:`
`prog = 1/X`
`elif df.loc[(df['Column C']=='B')]:`
`prog = 1/Y`
`else: print('this function doesnt work well')`
`return (prog)`
`for col in df.columns:`
`df[col]=new_norm(df)`

For both function I always have the same valueError:
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
Could you help me to understand what is going on here? is there any other way to create a df with the desire output?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `np.where` + `.div`:

```py
X = 10
Y = -10

df[["Column A", "Column B"]] = df[["Column A", "Column B"]].div(
    np.where(df["Column C"].eq("A"), X, Y), axis=0
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Column A  Column B Column C
0       0.2      0.40        A
1      -0.3     -0.30        B
2       0.0      0.04        A
3      -0.5     -0.70        B
4       0.3      0.20        A
5      -0.6     -0.00        B
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, this is very helpful, I really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using apply and call custom function to set new column based on whole row data. This makes it easier to read.
For example:

```
X=10
Y=5

def new_norm(row):
    #put your if/elif logic here, for example:
    if row['Column C'] == 'A':
         return row['Column A']/X #don't forget to return value for new column
    ....

df['newcol'] = df.apply(new_norm, axis=1) #call function for each row and add column 'newcol'
```

Function will allow to solve edge case (for example empty Column C or when there is different value than A or B etc.

Comment: Thanks Bracko, the function works well!!! appreciate it